# How to parse inner array in JSON response with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Let's say I've got a JSON response that is formed as such:

```
results: [
{
warehouse: West Side,
name: "Shipment 1",
contents: [
   {
     id: 94,
     product: "Apples",
     abbreviation: "apl"
   },
   {
     id: 64,
     product: "Grapes",
     abbreviation: "grp"
   },
  {
     id: 86
     product: "Watermelon",
     abbreviation: "wtrmelon"
   },
  {
     id: 15,
     product: "Peaches",
     abbreviation: "pch"
   },
 ]
},
{
warehouse: West Side 2,
name: "Shipment 2",
contents: [
 {
     id: 94,
     product: "Apples",
     abbreviation: "apl"
   },
 ]
}
```

What is the proper way to iterate through the inner array, ie, contents, to see if a shipment contained a certain item, say, apples? Ideally, I'd like to return only the shipments containing the sought after item as well. My line of thinking is you would obtain the size/length of the contents array, then iterate through it, looking for the string "apples". Am I on the right path here, or is there a better method of doing what I want?

Comment: You can use `json_decode` function

Comment: How do you get this response? i.e did you use, for example, `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: @ sємsєм Correct. This is just an API I am using, and then using the file_get_contents function, obtain the above. And I'd like to only display those that contain the wanted item, ie, apples for example. So I'm wondering how to parse that inner array best.